# Update products, terms and relations via SQL

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, sync

I am syncing the whole products database from an ORACLE database to a WooCommerce one.

To achieve this I am using [kettle](http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration/). My problem is:
I need to update the product count when I finish adding the products and linking them to categories.

I can see two possibilities:

- Run a PHP Script to update the count periodically (cron), something like this:

  function update_category_counters( $update_taxonomy = 'product_cat' ) 
  {

  ```
  $get_terms_args = array(
      'taxonomy'   => $update_taxonomy,
      'fields'     => 'ids',
      'hide_empty' => false,
  );

  $update_terms = get_terms( $get_terms_args );
  wp_update_term_count_now( $update_terms, $update_taxonomy );
  ```

  }
- Find a way to do all the things the function above does;

Here is what I've tried:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`xxxx`@`%` PROCEDURE `xxxx`()
BEGIN

delete from wp_options where option_name = 'product_cat_children';    

UPDATE wp_term_taxonomy SET count = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_term_relationships rel 
    LEFT JOIN wp_posts po ON po.ID = rel.object_id
    WHERE 
    rel.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id 
    AND 
    wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy NOT IN ('link_category')
    AND 
    po.post_status IN ('publish', 'future')
);
```

As seen here [so_18669256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669256/how-to-update-wordpress-taxonomiescategories-tags-count-field-after-bulk-impo).

Using this approach, I am able to list the categories in the front-end, but I can't open the admin's side product listing (`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1572864000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1495295696 bytes) in [...]/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/walkers/class-product-cat-dropdown-walker.php on line 66`).

Is it possible to set All needed fields (when updating categories counters for products) with a stored procedure? If so, how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about reducing the size of your query & have it run every 5 mins or so?

Comment: Products are added correctly, the problem is when I open an admin page to list WC's products...

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly you are loading all of your products on one page? Can you implement pageination?

Comment: The page is built in `wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product`

Comment: Look under "screen options" and cap the number of products per page at a lower number, say 20.

Comment: There were an error in the integration algorithm, somehow there were some hierarchical categories with the 'parent' set to itself. That's why I was getting the memory leak! Thank you for helping me!